# COUNT as a Window function throws error msg 4403 on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

This is my code:

```
WITH ActivityCTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        id,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) ctn
    FROM 
        dailyActivity_merged$
)
DELETE ActivityCTE
WHERE ctn <> 31
```

Could someone explain to me why `COUNT()` used in a window function throws an error message 4403?

> Cannot update the view or function 'ActivityCTE' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn4lF.png)

I'm trying to delete some records from my table that don't have 31 entries using a CTE.

Comment: We don't need an image when you've provided the query + error text.

Comment: And as to why - its by design.

Comment: I'd start with: `SELECT DISTINCT` since the error indicates: `or a DISTINCT`...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  It appears in your SQL as if you're trying to delete from the CTE, but that doesn't match your explanation.

Comment: @Andrew You can delete rows from a table via a CTE

Comment: You're deleting from the CTE, not any actual table. That doesn't really make sense. You could delete from the table based on the IDs selected by the CTE, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Perhaps I'm miss understanding you.  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2251a2f975d4eb832a933bcb5bf11b25   The source has two IDs and the final results only has one (for example)

Answer (score 1):

`Count(*)` is not the root of the error.

The error message details `...DISTINCT...`

```
WITH ActivityCTE AS(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY id) ctn
    FROM dailyActivity_merged$
)
DELETE FROM ActivityCTE
WHERE ctn <> 31
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I'd write it with a GROUP BY/HAVING, rather than a window function, and delete from the actual table, like this:

```
WITH ActivityCTE AS(
    SELECT id
    FROM dailyActivity_merged$
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING count(*) <> 31
)
DELETE dam
FROM dailyActivity_merged$ dam
INNER JOIN ActivityCTE cte on cte.id = dam.id
```